# How to Push Project Back to Fork "origin" in GitHub

Tags: git, bash, github

I need help.  This is the first time that I use Git Bash and GitHub.

I have successfully forked a project in GitHub and cloned the project to my local drive: C:\Users\my_local_name  under which the Git Bash created a directory with a name that is identical to that cloned project in GitHub, which is **vlerdas-subscribe**.

Now, I have completed all the changes made to the project on my local drive.  When I issued a push command using Git Bash at 
my_local_name@machine_name ~ (master)
$ git push origin master

I get 
  fatal: 'origin" does not appear to be a git repository
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

When I issued a push command at 
my_local_name@machine_name ~/**vlerdas-subscribe** (master)
$ git push origin master

I get
  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

Where did I make mistakes?  Here are the steps taken by me to fork and clone a GitHub project:

1. Go to GitHub and select the project of my interest, which is **vlerdas-subscribe**
2. Fork the project by clicking the Fork button (I created my GitHub username/password )
3. Clone the fork into the current directory in my machine using Git Bash.

my_local_name@machine_name ~
$ git clone https://github.com/my_GitHub_username/vlerdas-subscribe.git

1. To keep track of the original repository, I added another remote named “upstream”:

4.1.    I Change to the current directory in my machine

my_local_name@machine_name ~
$ cd vlerdas_subscribe

4.2.     Assigns the original repository to a remote called "upstream"

my_local_name@machine_name ~/vlerdas-subscribe (master)
$ git remote add upstream URL_Link_to_the_GitHub_project.git

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in the current version that does not prompt for username and password on HTTPS.

You can try:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'
```

or

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/project.git
```

For your second error:
You can check if your code is on Github by looking at the repo page (the Github link).

Did you add and commit your changes before pushing?

```
git add .
git commit -m 'commit message'
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your kind reply.

I have tried both of your suggestions.  I still cannot successfully push my code back to the "fork" origin.  (My attempts are shown below)

I think the second set of commands provided by you works a little better (in my environment).  When I push to code, the Git Bash says: "**error: src refspec master does not match any.**

I have another question:  In case that I could push my code back to the "fork", how do I examine my new code is in the GitHub?

MY ATTEMPTS:

After I entered the **first set of Git Bash commands**, I tried:
**git push origin master**

and I got:
vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git push origin master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

The second set of commands:

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git remote rm origin

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git remote add origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/{project_name}.git

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git push origin master
**error: src refspec master does not match any.**
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/{project_anme}.git'